# My blender doesn't open anymore

Tags: windows, installation

I'm having a problem with Blender 2.91.2
Whenever I try to open it, it just goes to the console and closes immediately.
Initially when this happened, it came up with a message about my userprefs file (I didn't quite catch the message exactly) so I searched this up online and it said I should delete my userprefs file, I did, and now when I open Blender, the console flashes briefly with no message at all now and doesn't open.
I've tried reinstalling Blender several times, I tried deleting certain files and using test builds of Blender, but none of these have worked.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out, thanks.

Comment: Update: I managed to open Blender, but when I tried to open a project file, it crashed and the issue came back (as well as the message about my userprefs file)

Comment: Start blender from cmd, it should show the error message

Comment: Update: It turns out I'm having the same problem with other programs on my computer as well where they will just get to the loading screen, but won't actually open. Not sure what's going on here.